# Real time capacitor voltage

Tags: voltage, capacitor

I have a simple circuit

- 12v adjustable voltage battery
- capacitor 15v - 1000uf
- coil of enamelled wire

[image]

If i set the battery to 12v so the capacitor will be charged 12v, then i decide to low the voltage of the battery to 4v then the capacitor will take time to get 4v

My target is get the same voltage of capacitor as same as the battery at once( real time) so if the battery is 12v so the capacitor is 12v, if the i low the voltage to 5v so the capacitor instant be 5v

Could be this done?

Comment: It depends on your components.  The way you have it wired up now with ideal components you will see the desired behavior - in simulation.  When you introduce real components with parasitic inductance, resistance, capacitance, and whatever an "adjustable voltage battery" is, you will see deviation from that: voltage sources will sag, time constants will come into play, etc.

Comment: Yes, this could be done but it depends on your input voltage. If your input voltage is not precisely 12V or 5V, your charge stored will also be changed accordingly. Although connecting the direct battery might damage the capacitor since the current through initially is very high due to the instant change in voltage . Thus try using a small resistor in series to operate safely. A small resistance puts almost no effect on rising time.

Comment: There's no such thing as "at once" in the real world. Everything takes a certain amount of time because of effects such as inductance, capacitance, resistance and propagation delays. You need to decide your design goal and how quickly you want things to happen and work backwards to make a practical design. The quicker you want to change the capacitor voltage, the more current you need to put into it or take out of it.

Comment: _"If i set the battery to 12v so the capacitor will be charged 12v, then i decide to low the voltage of the battery to 4v"_ - how will you do that?